# Give n. Display a triangle with the side of n stars empty inside

Tags: c++

This is my code, but i don't understand how can i print only 5 stars on last row. I tried with debugger i know the problem, but i don't know how to fix it.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * n; j++)
        {
            if (i + j == 6 || j - i == 4)
                cout << "*";
            else cout << " ";
                 
            if (i== n  && j % 2 !=0)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;

    }

}
```

This is the output.

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
* * * * *
```

Comment: It would help us if you provide the expected output

Comment: but n can be 1<=n <=10 , not only 5

Answer (score 0):

You can do as,

```
int n;
cin >> n;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

  for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
    cout << " ";
  }

  cout << "* ";
  
  if (i == n) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n - 2; j++) {
      cout << "* ";
    }
  } else {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 4; j++) {
      cout << " ";
    }
  }

  if (i != 1) cout << "*";

  cout << endl;
}
```